# Error when persisting entity with foreign key field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am try persist in database this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pessoa_juridica")
public class PessoaJuridica {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="cnpj")
    @Order(value=1)
    private String cnpj;

    @Column(name="razao_social")
    @Order(value=2)
    private String razaoSocial;

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )
    @Order(value=3)
    @JoinColumn(name="contato")
    private Contato contato;
}
```

but when I open the view with the form, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'pessoaJuridica.contato' of bean class [com.spring.loja.model.cliente.persistence.model.Cliente]: Could not instantiate property type [java.lang.Integer] to auto-grow nested property path: 
java.lang.InstantiationException:
java.lang.Integerorg.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.newValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:651)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createDefaultPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:620)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setDefaultValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:609)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:574)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:548)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:549)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:714)
org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:130)org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:120)org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:90)org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.fields_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f13(fields_jsp.java:2969)org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.fields_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f17(fields_jsp.java:2836)org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.fields_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f3(fields_jsp.java:2583)org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.fields_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f4(fields_jsp.java:2539)org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.fields_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f14(fields_jsp.java:2444)org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.fields_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(fields_jsp.java:242)org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.fields_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(fields_jsp.java:150)org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.fields_jsp._jspService(fields_jsp.java:115)org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.private_.cadastrar_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(cadastrar_jsp.java:166)org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.private_.cadastrar_jsp._jspService(cadastrar_jsp.java:88)org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1217)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

the setter/getter methods for `Contato` are:

```
public Integer getContato() {
    return contato.getId();
}

public void setContato(Integer id) {
    this.contato = new Contato(id);
}
```

the class `Contato`is this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contato")
public class Contato {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nome", unique=true)
    @Order(value=1)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="email")
    @Order(value=2)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="telefone")
    @Order(value=3)
    private String telefone;

    public Contato() {
        this.id = null;
        this.nome = null;
        this.email = null;
        this.telefone = null;
    }

    public Contato(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

If I try this for the setter/getter method:

```
public Contato getContato() {
    return contato;
}

public void setContato(Contato contato) {
    this.contato = contato;
}
```

the view is opened, but when I try submit the form, I get the error:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.spring.loja.model.contato.persistence.model.Contatoorg.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:314)org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:432)org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:314)org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:432)org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)com.spring.loja.config.generic.persistence.Dao.persist(Dao.java:32)com.spring.loja.config.generic.persistence.Dao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ddbbe880.invoke(<generated>)org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)com.spring.loja.model.cliente.persistence.ClienteHome$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$83cbd101.persist(<generated>)com.spring.loja.config.generic.service.service.cadastra(service.java:45)com.spring.loja.config.generic.service.service$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c92a3159.invoke(<generated>)org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)com.spring.loja.model.cliente.service.ClienteService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$71ccd54c.cadastra(<generated>)com.spring.loja.config.generic.controller.controller.cadastra(controller.java:42)com.spring.loja.config.generic.controller.controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c8cc444b.invoke(<generated>)org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640)com.spring.loja.model.cliente.controller.ClienteController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ffe13d4e_2.cadastra(<generated>)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

anyone knows the right way to persist the entity?

**UPDATE**

the field `contato` is mapped on the view as this:

```
<form:label path="pessoaJuridica.contato.id" class="label label-default">contato</form:label>
<form:select path="pessoaJuridica.contato.id" class="form-control select embed" data-lista="${url}" data-altera="${altera}" data-remove="${remove}"/>
```

**UPDATE 2**

In database, this is the how tables are created:

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa_juridica
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  cnpj character varying(255),
  razao_social character varying(255),
  contato integer,
  CONSTRAINT pessoa_juridica_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_eaa4oxajsuofatiyag213dio9 FOREIGN KEY (contato)
      REFERENCES contato (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE pessoa_juridica
  OWNER TO klebermo;


CREATE TABLE contato
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  email character varying(255),
  nome character varying(255),
  telefone character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT contato_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT uk_rrtn7wgfxo0jfwkhby23f72cn UNIQUE (nome)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE contato
  OWNER TO klebermo;
```

Comment: Can you post your code from view when you using second approach of setter/getter?

Comment: I just add to the question the code related to the field `contato`. BTW, the code is the same for the both approaches.

Comment: By looking your Exception, I think you have `<form:form>` modelAttribute to `Cliente` object and that object will have have `PessoaJuridica` object is this correct?

Comment: @Amogh yes, you are right.

Comment: Sorry for asking questions again n again but I m not able to replicate the issue, Tell me one when you submit form `pessoaJuridica.contato.id` control (<form:select>) selected value or not coz I m getting error only when I do not select value

Comment: @Amogh yes, I select one value. If I don't select a value, no error is displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58878/discussion-between-amogh-and-kleber-mota).

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, the join column name is not the name of the object you are joining to, but the name of the column on the object you are joining to.

Comment: I guess, He should use `@JoinColumn(name="id")`

Comment: @Amogh I believe so, because it is a column directive for the database structural details.  JPA uses the java type to determine which object to join to, so it's not a java class join directive.

Comment: @Amogh glad to hear you tried that, but did you also put a primary key annotation in `contacto`'s `id` field?  Can't join on a non-primary key, and since you are mixing your java directives with your database layout directives, you have a java `id` but no database directive about the primary key field...

Comment: @EdwinBuck `@Id` is primary key annotation, Isn't it?

Comment: @KleberMota Can you share with us your database tables?

Comment: @KleberMota At first glance contato(pessoa_juridica) has a integer datatype instead id(contato) is serial. This mismatch could cause the exception

Comment: @EdwinBuck, Actually @KleberMota's problem is he wants to save `PessoaJuridica` with reference value of `Contato`. where `Contato` is populated in select/combo box. So when submit is hit DAO is trying to persist `PessoaJuridica` , Which tries to save `Contato` also but its already their in Table.

Answer (score 0):

You told JPA to cascade all! and passed detached object to save, that is an issue.

According to [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive).

> CascadeType.PERSIST: cascades the persist (create) operation to
>   associated entities persist() is called or if the entity is managed

You said `@OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )` means it will apply all Transitive persistence.

So removing `cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}` will solve the prob.

```
@OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Order(value=3)
@JoinColumn(name="contato")
private Contato contato;
```

Comment: See the same question posted by Me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185747/dont-want-to-persist-one-to-one-entity

Comment: Hi again. I try here and works! But only if I select one value for `contato`. If I don't select a value, I get this error: `object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`. ANy ideas how to solve this for both cases?

Comment: @KleberMota, if `contato` in `PessoaJuridica` remains NULL then it will save PessoaJuridica without foreign key.

Comment: But this is not happening, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: @KleberMota, after submit on controller you can check whether `model.PessoaJuridica.contato.id==null` then make `model.PessoaJuridica.contato=null` then persist(PessoaJuridica)

Comment: Still nothing. I try modify my view to use this `<form:option value="${null}" label=""/>` and work for a moment, but I change something (what was I can't remember) and now I got the same error (only when the field is null).