# Don't want to persist one-to-one entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have two class `Employee` and `Department`.

In `Employee` I have written:

```
@OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="deptID")    
private Department department;
```

And `Department` class having Id and Name. (Just like Master of department).

I have a view where I am selecting `Department` using select/combo box. When I submit form and pass `Employee` object to persist it gives `detached entity passed to persist`. I want to save only employee entity with foreign key value, whereas `Department` is already having records.

Comment: Are that new employees or are that employees from the database. When the employees had a id. You should use merge.

Comment: Yes,from view employee details are captured then only employee get saved to DB.

Comment: please delete the CascadeAll, than it works?.The Departments are already saved (i think you load the select list from db) and with the cascade all you try to "persist" the oneToOne departments again.

Comment: @pL4Gu33, I tried by removing `CascadeAll` and run by junit test case I can see insert query on console on employee but nothing is saved in DB Table

Comment: but the exception is away? Have you commit?

Comment: That is not a OneToOne relationship, but a ManyToOne (in the entity Employee)

Comment: @pL4Gu33,Sorry I forgot to commit :) :P, It saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told JPA cascade all! and passed detached object to save, that is an issue. According to [Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive)
`CascadeType.PERSIST` works when you persist department when you persists employee.
As per hibernate doc:
`CascadeType.PERSIST: cascades the persist (create) operation to associated entities persist() is called or if the entity is managed`
So your options:

- Pass managed or transient department object attached to employee
  object.
- Merge detached one before persisting?
- Remove cascade all and select only cascade types you need
- Remove cascade type at all.

See hibernate doc