# How to add Many to one filed in Spring MVC and Hibernate Validator?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. I Have two entities Hello and HelloOneToMany. HelloOneToMany have a one to many relationship with Hello.My problem is that the hello object is not set when its arrived into the HelloOneToMany Controller from oneToMany.jsp as Post Request.But when its a GET request its is perfectly shown in the Hello Select box.But i cant save the HelloOneToMany Object.Because Hibernate Validator shows its not an object of Hello.

My Validator Error is

> [Field error in object 'helloOneToMany' on field 'hello': rejected
>   value [com.kmml.model.Hello@22180d6]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.helloOneToMany.hello,typeMismatch.hello,typeMismatch.com.kmml.model.Hello,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [helloOneToMany.hello,hello]; arguments []; default message
>   [hello]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.kmml.model.Hello' for
>   property 'hello'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [com.kmml.model.Hello] for property 'hello': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found]]

My Hello Model is

```
package com.kmml.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Hello {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="hello",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<HelloOneToMany> helloOneToMany= new ArrayList<HelloOneToMany>();

    public List<HelloOneToMany> getHelloOneToMany() {
        return helloOneToMany;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setHelloOneToMany(List<HelloOneToMany> helloOneToMany) {
        this.helloOneToMany = helloOneToMany;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My HelloOneToMany Model is

```
package com.kmml.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class HelloOneToMany {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne()
    private Hello hello;

    public Hello getHello() {
        return hello;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setHello(Hello hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

My Hello Controller is

```
package com.kmml.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.kmml.model.Hello;
import com.kmml.service.HelloService;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private HelloService helloService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("hello", new Hello());
        return "addUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sayHelloTwo( @Valid @ModelAttribute("hello")  Hello hello,BindingResult result )
    {
        System.out.println(result.hasErrors());
        System.out.println("Name:" +hello.getName());
        if(!result.hasErrors())
        {
            helloService.save(hello);
        }
        return "addUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting/{helloId}" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHelloUpdate(Model model,@PathVariable long helloId)
    {
        model.addAttribute("hello", helloService.find(helloId));

        return "addUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting/{helloId}" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sayHelloUpdateTwo(@Valid @ModelAttribute("hello")  Hello hello,BindingResult result,@PathVariable long helloId)
    {

        System.out.println(result.hasErrors());
        System.out.println("Name:" +hello.getName());
        System.out.println("Name:" +hello.getId());
        hello.setId(helloId);

        if(!result.hasErrors())
        {
            helloService.update(hello);
        }
        return "addUser";
    }
}
```

My HelloOneToMany Controller is

```
package com.kmml.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.kmml.model.HelloOneToMany;
import com.kmml.service.HelloOneToManyService;
import com.kmml.service.HelloService;

@Controller
public class HelloOneToManyController {

    @Autowired
    private HelloOneToManyService helloOneToManyService;
    @Autowired
    private HelloService helloService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(Model model)
    {

        model.addAttribute("helloOneToMany", new HelloOneToMany());                      
        model.addAttribute("hellos",helloService.findAll());

        return "oneToMany";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sayHelloTwo( @Valid @ModelAttribute("helloOneToMany")  HelloOneToMany helloOneToMany,BindingResult result )
    {
        System.out.println(result.hasErrors());
        System.out.println(result.getAllErrors());
        System.out.println("Name:" +helloOneToMany.getName());
        System.out.println("Name:" +helloOneToMany.getHello());
        if(!result.hasErrors())
        {
            helloOneToManyService.save(helloOneToMany);
        }
        return "oneToMany";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello/{helloOneToManyId}" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHelloUpdate(Model model,@PathVariable long helloOneToManyId)
    {
        model.addAttribute("helloOneToMany", helloOneToManyService.find(helloOneToManyId));

        return "oneToMany";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello/{helloOneToManyId}" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sayHelloUpdateTwo(@Valid @ModelAttribute("helloOneToMany")  HelloOneToMany helloOneToMany,BindingResult result,@PathVariable long helloOneToManyId)
    {

        System.out.println(result.hasErrors());
        System.out.println("Name:" +helloOneToMany.getName());
        System.out.println("Name:" +helloOneToMany.getId());
        helloOneToMany.setId(helloOneToManyId);

        if(!result.hasErrors())
        {
            helloOneToManyService.update(helloOneToMany);
        }
        return "oneToMany";
    }

}
```

My oneToMany.jsp is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form commandName="helloOneToMany">
<form:input path="name"/>
<form:errors path="name"/>
<br>
<form:select path="hello">
<form:options items="${hellos}"  itemLabel="name" itemId="id" />
</form:select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My intention was to add my selected object from the selection box to my next object.How to do this? Please help

Comment: OMG!! First its so much long question, Readers may ignore coz of length, I understand why you posted all this, but for simplicity Just post only necessary part of code and post full file if requested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when persisting entity with foreign key field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182540/error-when-persisting-entity-with-foreign-key-field)

Comment: Please check answer given by me on this (question)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182540/error-when-persisting-entity-with-foreign-key-field/25186366#25186366] he also want the same solution like you, selecting foreign key from select box and at the time save he don't want to save in foreign entity, I guess I m right?

Comment: @Amogh Hai Amogh i am new to this environment that is why i am posting too big. According to Your reference the problem is in @JoinColumn(name="id") is the Problem. I added that one but it doesnt works.Still my helloOneToMany.hello have a null value.

Comment: No actually problem is `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` removing this ll solve, I guess